# firebase error while trying to get SHA certificate fingerprints?

Tags: firebase, certificate, flutter, sha

While trying to get SHA certificate fingerprints I run this line and that was the result 
line:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

What else should I do to solve this error?

```
C:\>keytool -list -v -keystore %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
Illegal option:  sisy\.android\debug.keystore
keytool -list [OPTION]...

Lists entries in a keystore

Options:

 -rfc                    output in RFC style
 -alias <alias>          alias name of the entry to process
 -keystore <keystore>    keystore name
 -cacerts                access the cacerts keystore
 -storepass <arg>        keystore password
 -storetype <type>       keystore type
 -providername <name>    provider name
 -addprovider <name>     add security provider by name (e.g. SunPKCS11)
   [-providerarg <arg>]    configure argument for -addprovider
 -providerclass <class>  add security provider by fully-qualified class name
   [-providerarg <arg>]    configure argument for -providerclass
 -providerpath <list>    provider classpath
 -v                      verbose output
 -protected              password through protected mechanism

Use "keytool -help" for all available commands
```

Comment: Does "%USERPROFILE%" contain a space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `%USERPROFILE%` returns a value with a space in it.
Try wrapping in quotes like

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Comment: It finallly workeeed. Thanks a lot for help., really appreciate it

Comment: Glad to hear :-)

Comment: holy dammmmm!!!
also working for this link's instruction from firebase init step: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

i've edited $USERPROFILE% to C:\Users\my name and then wrapped whole path(= C:\Users\my name\.android\debug.keystore) with double quotes and this finally worked!!! (final  input => keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\my name\.android\debug.keystore")

Seems like it is different from mac os terminal commands! Thank you so moooooooouuuuch!! [: